# Shift right arithmetic

Tags: assembly, mips

Please have a look the following code:

```
addi $t1,$zero,-32
sra $t0,$t1,2
```

-32 = 0010 1111 1111

after >> 2: 0000 1011 1111 = -26

But the correct answer should be -8 after shifting, how does that happen??

Comment: `-32 = 0010 1111 1111`, nope

Comment: @nihulus: this is certainly not mips. SRA (shift right arithmetic) operationally gives you as a result the integer division of a number by 2^n. So for -32 and shifting 2 times it will give you -8

Comment: @gusbro thanks, got it!

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping this in the MARS simulator so you can look at register values with its debugger?  MIPS uses 2's complement, so `sra` shifts in copies of the sign bit (instead of zeros for logical right shift.)

Comment: get a calculator or do a manual conversion and you'll get `-32 = 1...1100000`. It's easy to see that `0010 1111 1111` is a positive number. And `-8 = 1...1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 0010 1111 1111

This seems to be a 12-bit number. MIPS CPUs use 32-bit numbers.

So no matter which operation your program performs: The bits `0010 1111 1111` cannot describe the full content of a register!

> -32 = 0010 1111 1111
>
> 0000 1011 1111 = -26

I tried different common ways how binary numbers are stored and written, including BCD!

I have no idea how `0010 1111 1111` and `0000 1011 1111`should represent the numbers -32 and -26!

Just like decimal numbers, binary numbers are typically written from right to left:

The rightmost digit has the value 2^0 (1), the digit left of it 2^1 (2), the digit left of it 2^2 (4) and so on.

This means that `000 ... 000 1011 1111` is 128+32+16+8+4+2+1 = 191.

I have also seen people writing numbers the other way (so they write 191 as `11111101`). However, such people have to keep in mind that the words "left" and "right" (`sra` = shift **right** arithmetic) have the inverse meaning then!

> -32 = ...

There are different methods how negative numbers are stored in CPU registers:

- Sign and positive number
  (Typically used for floating-point)
- One's complement
  (Used for checksum calculations in IPv4, TCP and UDP)
- Integer with offset
  (Often used in fixed-point arithmetic)
- (Pseudo-) Symmetric numeral systems
  (The preferred way for ternary computing devices but normally not used on binary computers)
- Two's complement

Nearly all modern binary computers and CPUs use **two's complement**. This is also true for MIPS CPUs.

Because you wrote "-32 = 0010 1111 1111", I assume that you did not understand how two's complement works:

In the two's complement system, the left bit is the sign of the number. If the left bit is one, the number is negative. If the left bit is zero, the number is positive or zero.

(Please note that this is **not** true for all the methods storing negative numbers that I mentioned above.)

By inverting all bits of a two's complement number `x`, we get the number `-(x+1)`. This means:

```
 31 =   32-1  = 00...0011111
-32 = -(31+1) = 11...1100000
```

> after >> 2 ...

... we get a result of `111111...111000`:

The right two bits are removed and two "new" bits are added on the left side. Because this is an arithmetic shift, this is done by "copying" the left bit of the original number:

The left bit is "1", so two "1" bits are added on the left side.

> But the correct answer should be -8 after shifting, how does that happen??

The left bit of "111111...111000" is one. So this is a negative number.

Now we apply the "invert all bits" rule again; `x` is the value in the register:

```
x      = 111...111000
-(x+1) = 000...000111 = 7

-(x+1) = 7
```

This means: `x = (-8)`

Comment: How do you get `0000 1011 1111 = -26`?  In 12-bit 2's complement, 1's complement, or sign/magnitude, it's a positive number.

Comment: @PeterCordes This is why I wrote that I have no idea why the user says that `0000 1011 1111` is -26. Using the "integer with offset" method (used in fixed-point calculations) for storing numbers, any bit pattern may have *any* meaning... So even `0000 0000 0001` may mean "-26".

Comment: Oh right, that was in a quote block from the question, sorry.